# Do not decode utf8 in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo = MongoClient('mongodb://admin:pass@127.0.0.1:27017/web_cache?authSource=admin')['web_cache']['pages']
for x in mongo.find({"status" : 1},{ "_id": 0, "url": 1, "effective_url": 1, "content" : 1, "Content-Type" : 1  }):
   print(x['content'])
   break
```

get error:

```
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

*content* has string mongo type. However *content* stores binary data. How to read *content* field in pymongo without utf8 decoding?

linux ubuntu
mongo 2.6.10
python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

**You could try to implement MongoClient as below:**

```
mongo = MongoClient('mongodb://admin:pass@127.0.0.1:27017/web_cache?authSource=admin', unicode_decode_error_handler='ignore') ....
```

Adding that `unicode_decode_error_handler='ignore`' statement in MongoClient.

If the error continue, you must upload pymongo version to 3.9.0 or superior:

```
pip install pymongo==3.9.0
```